# iOS: random method invocations due to memory leaks?

Tags: ios, debugging, memory-leaks

Today a serious problem arose for me. Suddenly my app became to an inconsistent state, I checked all logs (hopefully I have pretty much of them automatically saving in a file) and found out that there was an undesirable method invocation. The method just reset my core data stack.

I spent hours trying to find out how that was possible but found nothing but a few memory leaks. Is it possible that the memory leak caused a wrong, random, undesirable method invocation?

UPDATE:
my mistake, looks like my logs should be more detailed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if we speak of not freeing the allocated memory. This bug cost you just available memory.

Yes, if we speak of using an object reference after memory was freed. This should normally end with a exception if the object isn't there anymore. In case of primitive datatypes you might actually hit a memory address that will can change critical things - as long it is in your sandbox.

Example: I my very first app I was deserializing an int array from Core Data, but I kept writing more values than I had allocated as int array before. Result: Random crashes in different classes and Core Data.

Yes it is possible to ruin data that way - just very unlikely.

Comment: Was it a C array (I think no, since deserializing is mentioned, but just curious) that you had problem with? Thanks.

Comment: At that time ints where much faster than NSNumber so I went that way for performance reasons. Wasnt the best solution. :) It was also just an example how messing with the memory can go wrong. That bug kept me searching for some days. Anyhow it doesn't necessarily apply to you situation.

Comment: So it was a C array (not an array consisted of `NSInteger`, I meant) that you got back from CoreData? And may I ask, how were you finally be able to nail down the cause? Thanks again.

Comment: Since Core Data seemed to have issues I was going though all the Core Data related code. Noticed then that I try to store 100 values in an c array with 25 values. Copy and paste of a similar method that had 25 values and I simply forgot to adjust that code.

Comment: I see, I guess one of those C `*alloc` friends came to your rescue eventually. Alles klar, danke.

Comment: Gerne.:) Es ist immer schwer von aussen auf ein Problem zu sehen.